# Incompatible types: int and boolean. How to re-write if statement?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write this if statement:

```
public void currentState(boolean x)
    {
        boolean timeOn = true;
        boolean timeOff = false;
        if (x ==(0)) {
            x = timeOff;
        } else {
            x = timeOn;
        }
    }
```

`if (x ==(0)` does not work which I fully understand, but how would you re-write this so that x can be compared to 0?

Comment: how can a boolean be `0`?. Are you  trying to compare it x with `true`?

Comment: Why do you need to compare boolean x to 0? Why not just check `if (x) { }` or `!x`?

Comment: A `boolean` can just be `true` or `false`....

Comment: what 0 stands for true or false

Comment: The function does not return, calling the function does nothing.

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't actually know why I was trying to use an int when I could have just said `iif (x == false) {
            x = timeOff;
        }`

Comment: Java is type safe, it doesn't accept or allow incompatible types comparison.  As such you can't use `==` operator on a `boolean` and `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use two values - `true` and `false` if you're dealing with boolean. 0 is not one of them.

You could write the statement like this:

```
if (x == false) {
    x = timeOff;
} else {
    x = timeOn;
}
```

However, this if statement is meaningless. It is equivalent to:

```
if (x == false) {
    x = false;
} else {
    x = true;
}
```

It basically says "if x is false, make it false". You might want to reconsider what your method does.

EDIT:

You can also rewrite it like this:

```
if (x == true) {
    x = timeOff;
} else {
    x = timeOn;
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if (x) {
    x = timeOff;
} else {
    x = timeOn;
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
x = !x;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x) { // This will do.
            x = timeOff;
        } else {
            x = timeOn;
}
```

`if statements` can have only a boolean result arguments. so `x` is already a boolean with a value like `true/false`. you can't compare boolean values to `0`.

`==` is a relational operator that compare 2 values if they are `equal`, that results into a boolean output. There are many `relational operator` that compares 2 value according to that operator. You can read it here to fully understand how it works. [Summary of Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Java,a boolean data type can have only two possible values true and false.So,It can not be compared to 0.So either you need to make x as an int or you should check x with a valid boolean value like if(x == true)/if(x == false)

Comment: There is no need to check that `x==true` and `x==false`. It's enough to check `if(x)` and `if(!x)`.

Comment: Yes you are right,just added to make it simple to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing x==(0) in your code with !x as follows, x is a boolean. if x is (false or 0 or null), !x will be true, and anyother case !x will return false as required for you..

```
public void currentState(boolean x)
    {
        boolean timeOn = true;
        boolean timeOff = false;
        if (!x) {
            x = timeOff;
        } else {
            x = timeOn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is a type safe language. Therefore you can't use the `==`operator to compare two incompatible types, in this case `boolean` and the `int` literal value `0`. So you can either do one of these two things:

1. Pass an `int` parameter

   `public void currentState(int x){
       if (x == 0) {
         //code
       } else {
         //code
       }
    }`
2. Pass a `boolean` as in your orginal case

   `public void currentState(boolean x){
       if (x) {
         //code
       } else {
         //code
       }
    }`